# When is a continuous map $f: M \longrightarrow N$ between smooth manifolds homotopic to a smooth one?

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I know there have been similar questions here, but I haven't been able to completely pin down the precise conditions on $M$ and $N$. I have seen one proof of this that uses tubular neighborhood existence, which kind of assumes that $N$ is closed.

1. Do we have to have either of them compact?
2. Can either have a boundary?

The answer will clarify a few things in my reading. Thanks.

Comment: I think the key fact is Whitney approximation theorem. Embedding $N$ inside $\Bbb R^k$ for some $k$ (use Whitney embedding here), I can approximate, in the uniform norm, $f : M \to N \subset \Bbb R^k$ by a sequence of smooth maps. Thus $f'$ be a map $M \to \Bbb R^k$ close enough so it fits in a tubular nbhd $U$ of $N$ in $\Bbb R^k$. $p : U \to N$ be the bundle projection. $p \circ f' : M \to N$ is our candidate for the smooth map. I think a homotopy is obtained by looking at $p \circ H$ where $H$ homotopes $f'$ to $f$ by contracting along the fibers of $U$

Comment: (this is a vague sketch: anyone can feel free to debunk the idea if it's unworkable)

Comment: No, $M$ and $N$ need not be compact, and either may have boundary. For a reference, see Hirsch's ''Differential Topology'' Theorem 3.3. You may want to look at Theorem 2.6 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in the comments: The manifold is allowed to be non-compact and have boundary. Moreover, if one knows that the map is already smooth on a closed subset we can take the approximating function to coincide on this closed subset. This is answered in Hirsch' Differential Topology.

Ps: Tubular neighborhoods also exist for non-compact embedded submanifolds. This is also in Hirsch' book.